# How to identify with a formula in excel if it is the 1st 2nd 3rd month in quarter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a formula to identify if a month it is the 1st 2nd 3rd month in quarter

I tried with MOD(MONTH(A1),3), but the 3rd month in the quarter is shown as zero

[image]

I can use a condition where IF(MOD(MONTH(A1),3)=0,3,MOD(MONTH(A1),3)), but I'm wondering if there is something a bit more straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=MOD(MONTH(A1)-1,3)+1` As MOD calculates the remainder we need to extract 1 from the month and later add 1 to avoid 0 value.